# JMX for Go[lang]

Tags: go, jmx

Is there something like JMX for the go language?

On the internet I already found [GMX](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/02/05/introducing-gmx-runtime-instrumentation-for-go-applications) but I would ideally like something that I can not only use to export values, but also use to set the values of instrumented variables.

Comment: i don't have any idea about this one. try here http://godoc.org/-/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not *exactly* GMX like but I think it can solve your problem. http://golang.org/pkg/expvar/

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at it and see if it fits my needs!